# When minimizing a view, root controller contents also minimize swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Hi there I am trying to recreate apple musics miniplayer controller. There is a view that shows details about the song playing such as the song name, artist name, cover art and so forth like apple music. When a user clicks the dismiss button on the top of that controller, it minimizes it to a view just above the tabBar revealing the rootview behind the view. The only problem is that my code is causing an issue that when the view is minimized, instead of minimizing the view that shows the information about the current song being played, it minimizes all the views and leaves just a black screen. I'm not sure what is causing the issue but I will provide the code for my tabBar controller which houses the code to minimize and maximize the view and then the other controller which calls the function created in the tabBar controller to minimze and maximize the view as well as screen shots of what is happening. Thank you for taking the time to look at this. If anything is unclear please let me know.

TabBarController Code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var user: User? {
        didSet {
            guard let nav = viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController else { return }
            guard let feed = nav.viewControllers.first as? FeedController else { return }
            feed.user = user
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchUser()

        setupDetailsPlayerView()

//        perform(#selector(minimizePlayerDetails), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)
//        perform(#selector(maximizePlayerDetails), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)
    }


    @objc func minimizePlayerDetails() {

        maximizeTopAnchorConstraint.isActive = false
        minimizeTopAnchorConstraint.isActive = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

//            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        })
    }

    @objc func maximizePlayerDetails() {
        maximizeTopAnchorConstraint.isActive = true
        maximizeTopAnchorConstraint.constant = 0
        minimizeTopAnchorConstraint.isActive = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        })

    }

    func fetchUser() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        UserService.shared.fetchUser(uid: uid) { user in
            self.user = user
        }
    }


    let playerDetailsView = PlayerDetailController.initFromNib()

    var maximizeTopAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var minimizeTopAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    fileprivate func setupDetailsPlayerView() {
        print("setting up details view")

//        view.addSubview(playerDetailsView)
        view.insertSubview(playerDetailsView, belowSubview: tabBar)


        playerDetailsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        maximizeTopAnchorConstraint = playerDetailsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: view.frame.height)
        maximizeTopAnchorConstraint.isActive = true

        minimizeTopAnchorConstraint = playerDetailsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.topAnchor, constant: -64)
//        minimizeTopAnchorConstraint.isActive = true

        playerDetailsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        playerDetailsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        playerDetailsView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true



    }
}
```

function being called in songcontroller:

```
   @IBAction func dismissTapped(_ sender: Any) {

            guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
                let sceneDelegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate
                else {
                    return
            }
            let viewController = TabBarController()
            sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController
            viewController.minimizePlayerDetails()
            print("clicked")
            self.removeFromSuperview()

        }
```

Screenshots of what is happening:

Normal View:
[image: normal view]

Minimized View:
[image: minimized view]

Answer (score 0):

If you've created the `TabBarController` by storyboard then the empty initialization you've provided won't work. You need to instantiate the `UIViewController` from the storyboard. This seems to be the reason why you're getting an empty `UITabBarController` when setting the `rootViewController`. Modify your button action `dismissTapped` like this:

```
@IBAction func dismissTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    //...
    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as? TabBarController
    sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    //...
}
```

Comment: So this code works and I am no longer having the issue of seeing a black screen. Only problem is when I am on another viewcontroller selected from my tabbar and I dismiss the view, the view minimizes but takes me back to the first controller on the tab bar, in this instance it takes me to the viewcontroller that has the house symbol every time I dismiss it. Any recommendation on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure, Why don't you ask this as a follow-up question explaining the details and post the link here and I'll surely take a look? Btw, if this answer helped with the black screen issue you had then mark it as right and upvote.